# How to make my game of life program object oriented?

Tags: java, oop, conways-game-of-life

I am trying to make my game of life program Object Oriented to follow my professor's style guide and not lose points, but I can't figure out how to do so with the way my program is coded.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.swing.*;

public class GameOfLife2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
static final Color[] color = { Color.LIGHT_GRAY, Color.BLUE };
// size in pixel of every label
static final int size = 15;
static final Dimension dim = new Dimension(size, size);

// the cells labels
private LifeLabel[][] label;
// timer that fires the next feneration
private Timer timer;
// generation counter
private int generation = 0;
private JLabel generationLabel = new JLabel("Generation: 0");
// the 3 buttons
private JButton bClear = new JButton("Clear"), bPause = new JButton("Pause"), bGo = new JButton("Go");
// the slider for the speed
JSlider slider = new JSlider(0, 5000); // 0 to 5000 milliseconds (5 seconds)
// state of the game (running or pause)
private boolean gameRunning = false;
// if the mouse is down or not
private boolean mouseDown = false;

GameOfLife2(int nbRow, int nbCol) {
    super("GameOfLife");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    // create the labels (2 more on each size) these wont be shown
    // but will be used in calculating the cells alive around
    label = new LifeLabel[nbRow + 2][nbCol + 2];
    for (int r = 0; r < nbRow + 2; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < nbCol + 2; c++) {
            label[r][c] = new LifeLabel();
        }
    }

    // panel in the center with the labels
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(nbRow, nbCol, 1, 1));
    panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));

    // add each label (not the one on the border) to the panel and add to
    // each of them its neighbours
    for (int r = 1; r < nbRow + 1; r++) {
        for (int c = 1; c < nbCol + 1; c++) {
            panel.add(label[r][c]);
            label[r][c].addNeighbour(label[r - 1][c]); // North
            label[r][c].addNeighbour(label[r + 1][c]); // South
            label[r][c].addNeighbour(label[r][c - 1]); // West
            label[r][c].addNeighbour(label[r][c + 1]); // East
            label[r][c].addNeighbour(label[r - 1][c - 1]); // North West
            label[r][c].addNeighbour(label[r - 1][c + 1]); // North East
            label[r][c].addNeighbour(label[r + 1][c - 1]); // South West
            label[r][c].addNeighbour(label[r + 1][c + 1]); // South East
        }
    }

    // now the panel can be added
    add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    // the bottom panel with the buttons the generation label and the slider
    // this panel is formed grid panels
    panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 3));
    // another panel for the 3 buttons
    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 3));
    bClear.addActionListener(this);
    buttonPanel.add(bClear);
    bPause.addActionListener(this);
    bPause.setEnabled(false); // game is pause the pause button is disabled
    buttonPanel.add(bPause);
    bGo.addActionListener(this);
    buttonPanel.add(bGo);
    // add the 3 buttons to the panel
    panel.add(buttonPanel);
    // the generation label
    generationLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    panel.add(generationLabel);
    // the slider
    slider.setMajorTickSpacing(1000);
    slider.setMinorTickSpacing(250);
    slider.setPaintTicks(true);
    // the labels for the Slider
    Hashtable<Integer, JLabel> labelTable = new Hashtable<Integer, JLabel>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
        labelTable.put(new Integer(i * 1000), new JLabel("" + i));
    }
    slider.setLabelTable(labelTable);
    slider.setPaintLabels(true);

    panel.add(slider);
    // in the JFrame
    add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    // put the frame on
    setLocation(20, 20);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
    // start the thread that run the cycles of life
    timer = new Timer(5000 - slider.getValue(), this);
}

// called by the Timer and the JButtons
public synchronized void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // test the JButtons first
    Object o = e.getSource();
    // the clear button
    if (o == bClear) {
        timer.stop(); // stop timer
        gameRunning = false; // flag gamme not running
        bPause.setEnabled(false); // disable pause button
        bGo.setEnabled(true); // enable go button
        // clear all cells
        for (int r = 1; r < label.length - 1; r++) {
            for (int c = 1; c < label[r].length - 1; c++) {
                label[r][c].clear();
            }
        }
        // reset generation number and its label
        generation = 0;
        generationLabel.setText("Generation: 0");
        return;
    }
    // the pause button
    if (o == bPause) {
        timer.stop(); // stop timer
        gameRunning = false; // flag not running
        bPause.setEnabled(false); // disable myself
        bGo.setEnabled(true); // enable go button
        return;
    }
    // the go button
    if (o == bGo) {
        bPause.setEnabled(true); // enable pause button
        bGo.setEnabled(false); // disable myself
        gameRunning = true; // flag game is running
        timer.setDelay(5000 - slider.getValue());
        timer.start();
        return;
    }
    // not a JButton so it is the timer
    // set the delay for the next time
    timer.setDelay(5000 - slider.getValue());
    // if the game is not running wait for next time
    if (!gameRunning)
        return;
    ++generation;
    generationLabel.setText("Generation: " + generation);
    for (int r = 0; r < label.length; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < label[r].length; c++) {
            label[r][c].checkState();
        }
    }
    for (int r = 0; r < label.length; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < label[r].length; c++) {
            label[r][c].updateState();
        }
    }
}

// to start the whole thing as a Java application
public static void main(String[] arg) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new GameOfLife2(30, 50);
        }
    });
}

// A class that extends JLabel but also check for the neigbour
// when asked to do so
class LifeLabel extends JLabel implements MouseListener {
    private int state, newState;
    private int nbNeighbour;
    private LifeLabel[] neighbour = new LifeLabel[8];

    LifeLabel() {
        state = newState = 0; // Dead
        setOpaque(true); // so color will be showed
        setBackground(color[0]);
        addMouseListener(this); // to select new LIVE cells
        this.setPreferredSize(dim);
    }

    // to add a neibour
    void addNeighbour(LifeLabel n) {
        neighbour[nbNeighbour++] = n;
    }

    // to see if I should live or not
    void checkState() {
        // number alive around
        int nbAlive = 0;
        // see the state of my neighbour
        for (int i = 0; i < nbNeighbour; i++)
            nbAlive += neighbour[i].state;
        // newState
        if (state == 1) { // if alive
            if (nbAlive < 2) // 1.Any live cell with fewer than two live
                                // neighbours dies
                newState = 0;
            if (nbAlive > 3) // 2.Any live cell with more than three live
                                // neighbours dies
                newState = 0;
        } else {
            if (nbAlive == 3) // 4.Any dead cell with exactly three live
                                // neighbours becomes a live cell
                newState = 1;
        }
    }

    // after the run switch the state to new state
    void updateState() {
        if (state != newState) { // do the test to avoid re-setting same
                                    // color for nothing
            state = newState;
            setBackground(color[state]);
        }
    }

    // called when the game is reset/clear
    void clear() {
        if (state == 1 || newState == 1) {
            state = newState = 0;
            setBackground(color[state]);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
    }

    // if the mouse enter a cell and it is down we make the cell alive
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
        if (mouseDown) {
            state = newState = 1;
            setBackground(color[1]);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
    }

    // if the mouse is pressed on a cell you register the fact that it is
    // down
    // and make that cell alive
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
        mouseDown = true;
        state = newState = 1;
        setBackground(color[1]);
    }

    // turn off the fact that the cell is down
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
        mouseDown = false;
    }
}
}
```

I have never been terribly good at making my programs object oriented and typically stick to one class, but I am currently being forced to make this program object oriented.

If you could not only help me to change this program to be OOP but also give me tips on how to take a program that is not OOP and make it that way, that would be absolutely fantastic.

Comment: One mor java specific thing, if you want to add a comment for a method, use the Javadoc comment : /** comment */, see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html

Answer (score 3):

There is only one way to really get into OO: practice. Think up a representation for the problem to solve, look for discernible entities in the elements you see and design classes to represent those elements. Plan the interaction and relationships between those elements.

Then implement and see what works well and what doesn't. You will learn, even from your bad choices, even if its only that a particular choice did not work out well.

For a start, imagine the game of life if it were a real, physical world before your eyes. Distinct entities should be readily aparent and thats a good start for designing.

Sure, we can suggest you to abstract this and that into one or the other object, but if you don't do the work yourself much of the choices will forever remain a mystery to you. Only be actually making your own choices you will really learn something.

Comment: I like this answer. That last paragraph hits the nail on the head. The more you think in OOP, the easier it becomes.

Answer (score 1):

OOP is about objects (As the name suggests :) ). So to improve your OOP programming, initially think what properties are common among components in your game.

You have already done that for lifeLabel. which has been set to a neighbour. Instead of this approach each neighbour should be an object and you could have a List. Then updating the state and checking the state could be minimized and easier to understand.

There wouldn't be many changes to make your code OOP